# animation with swipe to remove item of list view

Tags: android, animation, swipe

I created a listview, and with a swipe the items are deleted. I have added an animation to swipe. when I do a swipe of the animation on all the items of the listview but not one in which I made the swipe.
I'd like to figure out how I can do! thanks for your help!

```
noteList.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    historicX = event.getX();
                    historicY = event.getY();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (event.getX() - historicX < -DELTA) {
                        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.right);
                        v.startAnimation(animation);
                        // removing this notes
                        dbhelper.removeNote(items.get(position).getId());
                        // refreshing the listView
                        setNotes();

                        return true;
                    } else if (event.getX() - historicX > DELTA) {
                        // removing this notes
                        dbhelper.removeNote(items.get(position).getId());
                        // refreshing the listView
                        setNotes();

                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```